# Calculating Standard Deviation with JavaScript showing NaN in Textfield

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i want to calculate the standard deviation of 10 values from input types.
I am collecting them into an array and want to calculate my standard deviation.

Problem is, it always shows NaN when i run the function (with action "oninput")

My code is the following:

```js
function s10() {

                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                    var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                    var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                    var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                    var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value);
                    var n9 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value);
                    var n10 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input10').value);

                    var arr = [{
                        key: 'n1',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n2',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n3',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n4',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n5',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n6',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n7',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n8',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n9',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n10',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input10').value)
                    }, ];

                    const mean = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + n) / arr.length;
                    const variance = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + (n - mean) ** 2, 0) / (arr.length - 1);
                    document.getElementById('s').value = Math.sqrt(variance);
                }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
<input type="text" id="input2"/>
<input type="text" id="input3"/>
<input type="text" id="input4"/>
<input type="text" id="input5"/>
<input type="text" id="input6"/>
<input type="text" id="input7" />
<input type="text" id="input8" />
<input type="text" id="input9" />
<input type="text" id="input10" oninput="s10();" />
<input type="text" id="s" placeholder="standardDeviation" />
```

Comment: In your example code, many of your inputs do not exist. Also, you can simplify this by using `. valueAsNumber` instead of parsing the `.value`. You should probably provide sensible defaults as well, so `input && input.valueAsNumber || 0` to ensure the input exists and outputs a number. As soon as a non-number appears, your entire script will fall apart and output `NaN`.

Comment: when I am testing the code, I am always writing input1-10 with values (1,2,3,4,...). So it should not fail there, since it only executes when the input10 gets a value.

Comment: i just didnt post all of those input types in my example

Comment: Add a complete example, please, including your test inputs. How are we supposed to know it's working or not if we don't get the full picture? Also you should probably use `<input type="number" />` to be safe. Also have a look at adding it as an executable code snippet (the `<>` button will allow you to paste your HTML, CSS and JS and embed it so we can test it live in the browsers on SO itself)

Comment: i added my inputs, excluding all those scripts that are executed and working fine

Comment: not that easy to make it runable because its a really huge file :D i only posted one function which is not working, with the html fields that are used there

Comment: I just made it runnable, and the output is indeed NaN. But your inputs still have no value, so their value will probably be undefined. `parseFloat( undefined ) === NaN`, which introduces the logic that any math done with them is `NaN`...

Comment: but i dont get what the problem is, i am running several other fucntions with the same structure min, max, mean, ... and its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a modified example of your code. A couple of notes:

- When calculating the mean and variance, you were using `n` in the `reduce` callbacks, rather than `n.value`
- The first `reduce` function needed an initial value of 0
- I used `number` type inputs to make it easier to step through values
- `n.value || 0` will use `0` when the input is empty to prevent errors during addition

```html
<script>
  function s10() {
    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input1").value);
    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input2").value);
    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input3").value);
    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input4").value);
    var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input5").value);
    var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input6").value);
    var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input7").value);
    var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input8").value);
    var n9 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input9").value);
    var n10 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input10").value);

    var arr = [
      {
        key: "n1",
        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input1").value),
      },
      {
        key: "n2",
        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input2").value),
      },
      {
        key: "n3",
        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input3").value),
      },
      {
        key: "n4",
        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input4").value),
      },
      {
        key: "n5",
        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input5").value),
      },
      {
        key: "n6",
        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input6").value),
      },
      {
        key: "n7",
        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input7").value),
      },
      {
        key: "n8",
        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input8").value),
      },
      {
        key: "n9",
        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input9").value),
      },
      {
        key: "n10",
        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input10").value),
      },
    ];

    const mean = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + (n.value || 0), 0) / arr.length;
    const variance = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + ((n.value || 0) - mean) ** 2, 0) / (arr.length - 1);
    document.getElementById("s").value = Math.sqrt(variance);
  }
</script>
<input type="number" id="input1" />
<input type="number" id="input2" />
<input type="number" id="input3" />
<input type="number" id="input4" />
<input type="number" id="input5" />
<input type="number" id="input6" />
<input type="number" id="input7" />
<input type="number" id="input8" />
<input type="number" id="input9" />
<input type="number" id="input10" oninput="s10();" placeholder="Type here" />
<input type="text" id="s" placeholder="standardDeviation" />
```

Comment: Calculating a standard value with 0 included is falsy because statistically speaking standard deviation means the distribution normality of values based of the mean of the values. Yes ! zero doesn't affect the mean but if the cardinality of the sample is considered it would be wrong mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

Okay a couple of small bugs in your code:

When using your `arr`, you should keep in mind the number is located in `arr[item].value`, an is *not* the item itself. You tried counting with objects, which results in `NaN`.

When calculating the `mean`, you did not pass in an initial value, which means you started counting with `undefined`, which gives `NaN`, which propagates to all your code. So

```
const mean = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + n) / arr.length;
```

should be

```
const mean = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + n.value, 0) / arr.length;
```

The same rule applies for your `average` calculation, where `arr[item].value` is your value, not the item itself.

```js
function s10() {

  var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
  var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
  var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
  var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
  var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
  var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
  var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
  var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value);
  var n9 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value);
  var n10 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input10').value);

  var arr = [{
      key: 'n1',
      value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value)
  }, {
      key: 'n2',
      value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value)
  }, {
      key: 'n3',
      value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value)
  }, {
      key: 'n4',
      value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value)
  }, {
      key: 'n5',
      value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value)
  }, {
      key: 'n6',
      value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value)
  }, {
      key: 'n7',
      value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value)
  }, {
      key: 'n8',
      value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value)
  }, {
      key: 'n9',
      value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value)
  }, {
      key: 'n10',
      value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input10').value)
  }, ];

  const mean = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + n.value, 0) / arr.length;
  const variance = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + (n.value - mean) ** 2, 0) / (arr.length - 1);
                  
  document.getElementById('s').value = Math.sqrt(variance);
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input10" oninput="s10();" />
<input type="number" id="input1" value="1" />
<input type="number" id="input2" value="2" />
<input type="number" id="input3" value="3" />
<input type="number" id="input4" value="4" />
<input type="number" id="input5" value="5" />
<input type="number" id="input6" value="6" />
<input type="number" id="input7" value="7" />
<input type="number" id="input8" value="8" />
<input type="number" id="input9" value="9" />
<input type="number" id="s" placeholder="standardDeviation" />
```

Comment: thank you very much aswell :) sorry for my posting problems, i dont use this site so much.

Comment: Hey you can learn from this anyway, so it'll be fine. Now you can see how SO snippets work in your question, so have a look at it!

Comment: i posted an edit showing my calculation code, but i still dont get it running as a code snippet with ctrl + m :D

Comment: okay i somwhow made it work ^^

Answer (score 0):

I am not a JavaScript practionner, but I suggest the following:

- In case the user inputs only one value then std = 0
- In case it is more than one value the call to the calculations should be done everywhere for simplicity and real-time calculation.
- Building the array can be done dynamically for more inputs such that the input id is defined as `input{i}`.
- Checking for NaN is mandatory before accepting any value.

So the code could be,

```
<input type="text" id="input1" oninput="s10();"/>
<input type="text" id="input2" oninput="s10();"/>
<input type="text" id="input3" oninput="s10();"/>
<input type="text" id="input4" oninput="s10();"/>
<input type="text" id="input5" oninput="s10();"/>
<input type="text" id="input6" oninput="s10();"/>
<input type="text" id="input7" oninput="s10();" />
<input type="text" id="input8" oninput="s10();" />
<input type="text" id="input9" oninput="s10();" />
<input type="text" id="input10" oninput="s10();" />
<input type="text" id="s" placeholder="standardDeviation" />
```

````
function s10() {
  let arr = [];
  N = 10; // Can be changed to be identified dynamically
  for(i=1; i<=N; i++) {
    let input_id = "input"+String(i);
    let val = parseFloat(document.getElementById(input_id).value);
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
      arr.push(val);
    };
  };
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('s').value = NaN;
  }
  else if (arr.length == 1) {
    const variance = 0;
    document.getElementById('s').value = Math.sqrt(variance);
  } else {
    const mean = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + n) / arr.length;
    const variance = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + (n - mean) ** 2, 0) / (arr.length - 1);
    document.getElementById('s').value = Math.sqrt(variance);
  };
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calc1() {
                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1) / 1;
                    }
                    function calc2() {
                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);;
                        document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2) / 2;
                    }
                    function calc3() {
                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                        var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                        document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3;
                    }
                    function calc4() {
                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                        var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                        var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                        document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4;
                    }
                    function calc5() {
                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                        var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                        var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                        var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                        document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5) / 5;
                    }
                    function calc6() {
                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                        var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                        var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                        var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                        var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                        document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6) / 6;
                    }

                    function calc7() {
                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                        var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                        var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                        var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                        var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                        var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                        document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7) / 7;
                    }
                    function calc8() {
                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                        var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                        var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                        var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                        var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                        var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                        var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value);
                        document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8) / 8;
                    }

                    function calc9() {
                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                        var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                        var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                        var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                        var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                        var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                        var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value);
                        var n9 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value);
                        document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8 + n9) / 9;
                    }
                    function calc10() {
                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                        var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                        var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                        var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                        var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                        var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                        var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value);
                        var n9 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value);
                        var n10 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input10').value);
                        document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8 + n9 + n10) / 10;
                    }

                    function s10() {

                        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                        var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                        var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                        var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                        var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                        var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                        var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value);
                        var n9 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value);
                        var n10 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input10').value);

                        var arr = [{
                            key: 'n1',
                            value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value)
                        }, {
                            key: 'n2',
                            value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value)
                        }, {
                            key: 'n3',
                            value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value)
                        }, {
                            key: 'n4',
                            value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value)
                        }, {
                            key: 'n5',
                            value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value)
                        }, {
                            key: 'n6',
                            value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value)
                        }, {
                            key: 'n7',
                            value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value)
                        }, {
                            key: 'n8',
                            value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value)
                        }, {
                            key: 'n9',
                            value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value)
                        }, {
                            key: 'n10',
                            value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input10').value)
                        }, ];
                        arr.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
                            return obj1.value - obj2.value;
                        });
                        document.getElementById('min').value = arr[0].value;
                        arr.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
                            return obj2.value - obj1.value;
                        });
                        document.getElementById('max').value = arr[0].value;
                        const mean = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + (n.value || 0), 0) / arr.length;
                        const variance = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + ((n.value || 0) - mean) ** 2, 0) / (arr.length - 1);
                        const stabw = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + ((n.value || 0) - mean) ** 2, 0) / (arr.length);
                        document.getElementById("stichprobe").value = Math.sqrt(variance);
                        document.getElementById("-6s").value = mean - 6 * Math.sqrt(variance);
                        document.getElementById("+6s").value = mean + 6 * Math.sqrt(variance);
                        document.getElementById("s").value = Math.sqrt(stabw) / mean * 100;
                        document.getElementById("cp").value = (document.getElementById("rkmax").value - document.getElementById("rkmin").value) / (6 * Math.sqrt(variance));
                        var temp = 0.0;
                        if (document.getElementById("rkmax").value - mean <= mean - document.getElementById("rkmin").value) {
                            temp = document.getElementById("rkmax").value - mean;
                        } else {
                            temp = mean - document.getElementById("rkmin").value;
                        }

                        document.getElementById("cpk").value = temp / (3 * Math.sqrt(variance));
                    }
```

```html
rkmin:  <input type="number" id="rkmin" placeholder="Rk min" />
rkmax:  <input type="number" id="rkmax" placeholder="Rk max" />


              1:<input type="number" id="input1" oninput="calc1(); s10();" />
              2:<input type="number" id="input2" oninput="calc2(); s10();" />
              3:<input type="number" id="input3" oninput="calc3(); s10();" />
              4:<input type="number" id="input4" oninput="calc4(); s10();" />
              5:<input type="number" id="input5" oninput="calc5(); s10();" />
              6:<input type="number" id="input6" oninput="calc6(); s10();" />
              7:<input type="number" id="input7" oninput="calc7(); s10();" />
              8:<input type="number" id="input8" oninput="calc8(); s10();" />
              9:<input type="number" id="input9" oninput="calc9(); s10();" />
              10:<input type="number" id="input10" oninput="calc10(); s10();" />
                
                 <input type="text" readonly id="max" placeholder="Rk max" />
                <input type="text" readonly id="min" placeholder="Rk min" />
                <input type="text" readonly id="resultmittel" placeholder="Rk x&#772;" />
                <input type="text" readonly id="s" placeholder="Streuung [%]" />
                <input type="text" readonly id="stichprobe" placeholder="Stichprobe" />
                <input type="text" readonly id="+6s" placeholder="&micro; +6&sigma;" />
                <input type="text" readonly id="-6s" placeholder="&micro; -6&sigma;" />
                <input type="text" readonly id="cp" placeholder="Cp" />
                <input type="text" readonly id="cpk" placeholder="CpK" />
```

EDIT

So my calculations now work all together -> min, max, mean, variance, deviations (STABW & STABW.N in MS Excel) aswell as -6sigma and +6sigma and Cp and CpK.

It just isnt optimized to work with dynamic input values.

Thank you for your help people!

```
               <script>
                function calc1() {
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1) / 1;
                }
                function calc2() {
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);;
                    document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2) / 2;
                }
                function calc3() {
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                    document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3;
                }
                function calc4() {
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                    document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4;
                }
                function calc5() {
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                    var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                    document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5) / 5;
                }
                function calc6() {
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                    var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                    var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                    document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6) / 6;
                }

                function calc7() {
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                    var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                    var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                    var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                    document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7) / 7;
                }
                function calc8() {
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                    var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                    var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                    var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                    var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value);
                    document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8) / 8;
                }

                function calc9() {
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                    var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                    var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                    var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                    var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value);
                    var n9 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value);
                    document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8 + n9) / 9;
                }
                function calc10() {
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                    var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                    var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                    var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                    var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value);
                    var n9 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value);
                    var n10 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input10').value);
                    document.getElementById('resultmittel').value = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8 + n9 + n10) / 10;
                }

                function s10() {

                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value);
                    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value);
                    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value);
                    var n5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
                    var n6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value);
                    var n7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value);
                    var n8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value);
                    var n9 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value);
                    var n10 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input10').value);

                    var arr = [{
                        key: 'n1',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n2',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n3',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n4',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n5',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n6',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input6').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n7',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input7').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n8',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input8').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n9',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input9').value)
                    }, {
                        key: 'n10',
                        value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('input10').value)
                    }, ];
                    arr.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
                        return obj1.value - obj2.value;
                    });
                    document.getElementById('min').value = arr[0].value;
                    arr.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
                        return obj2.value - obj1.value;
                    });
                    document.getElementById('max').value = arr[0].value;
                    const mean = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + (n.value || 0), 0) / arr.length;
                    const variance = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + ((n.value || 0) - mean) ** 2, 0) / (arr.length - 1);
                    const stabw = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + ((n.value || 0) - mean) ** 2, 0) / (arr.length);
                    document.getElementById("stichprobe").value = Math.sqrt(variance);
                    document.getElementById("-6s").value = mean - 6 * Math.sqrt(variance);
                    document.getElementById("+6s").value = mean + 6 * Math.sqrt(variance);
                    document.getElementById("s").value = Math.sqrt(stabw) / mean * 100;
                    document.getElementById("cp").value = (document.getElementById("rkmax").value - document.getElementById("rkmin").value) / (6 * Math.sqrt(variance));
                    var temp = 0.0;
                    if (document.getElementById("rkmax").value - mean <= mean - document.getElementById("rkmin").value) {
                        temp = document.getElementById("rkmax").value - mean;
                    } else {
                        temp = mean - document.getElementById("rkmin").value;
                    }

                    document.getElementById("cpk").value = temp / (3 * Math.sqrt(variance));
                }
            </script>
 <input type="number" id="rkmin" placeholder="Rk min" />
        <input type="number" id="rkmax" placeholder="Rk max" />
            <input type="number" id="input1" oninput="calc1(); s10();"/>
            <input type="number" id="input2" oninput="calc2(); s10();"/>
            <input type="number" id="input3" oninput="calc3(); s10();"/>
            <input type="number" id="input4" oninput="calc4(); s10();"/>
            <input type="number" id="input5" oninput="calc5(); s10();"/>
            <input type="number" id="input6" oninput="calc6(); s10();"/>
            <input type="number" id="input7" oninput="calc7(); s10();"/>
            <input type="number" id="input8" oninput="calc8(); s10();"/>
            <input type="number" id="input9" oninput="calc9(); s10();"/>
            <input type="number" id="input10" oninput="calc10(); s10();"/>

            <input type="text" readonly id="max" placeholder="Rk max"/>
            <input type="text" readonly id="min" placeholder="Rk min"/>
            <input type="text" readonly id="resultmittel "placeholder="Rk x&#772;"/>
            <input type="text" readonly id="s" placeholder="Streuung [%]"/>
            <input type="text" readonly id="stichprobe" placeholder="Stichprobe"/>
            <input type="text" readonly id="+6s" placeholder="&micro; +6&sigma;"/>
            <input type="text" readonly id="-6s" placeholder="&micro; -6&sigma;"/>
            <input type="text" readonly id="cp" placeholder="Cp"/>
            <input type="text" readonly id="cpk" placeholder="CpK"/>
```